# PDFMiner squishing chunks of text together

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am using pdfminer3 to parse the text out of some pdf files. It usually parses out the text I need but often times it will just clump a lot of the text together to make it almost impossible to do anything with the text after that.
Here is an example of part of a file that it will pull:

OBAMA VICTORY FUND 2012* OBAMA VICTORY FUND 2012* OBAMA VICTORY FUND 20122500.003500.003000.002000.005000.00WAGA624 12TH AVE E APT C403 JAMES WOOD COURT4117 ORCHARD LAKE CT

I am trying to pull some of the addresses out of the resulting string and the lack of spaces between pieces of text pdfminer is pulling is making this task near impossible.

Here is the function I am using to convert the pdf into text:

```
def convert(self, fname, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(pages)

    output = StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = open(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close
    return text
```